# Passed anonymous callback function detected as undefined

Tags: jquery, callback, anonymous-function

The `next()` function in the code below passes an anonymous function to the `position()` function. The `position()` function positions the bubble(sort of a lightbox) in the DOM and at the end of the execution, it calls the anonymous function, which in turn, shows the bubble. Any idea why my anonymous function is undefined?

```
;(function ($) {

Bubble = {
    init: function() {
        $('.bubble:not(:first)').hide();    
        $(document).on('click', '.next', Bubble.next);
    },
    next: function() {
        $('.bubble').next().addClass('current');

        Bubble.position(function(){
            $('.current').fadeIn();     
        }); 
    },
    position: function(callback) {
        $('.current').css({ /**/ });
        callback(); // Console shows that 'callback' is undefined
    }
}

$(function() {
    Bubble.init();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: would you be kind and create some jsfiddle

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) containing your HTML markup as well, so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PJBxU/1/

Comment: It's not the actual code actually. But the implementation is the same basically. @ArunPJohny: Yeah, just tried it and it works in jsfiddle but it doesn't in my actual code. The code is huge. Any wild guess why such an error may occur?

Comment: you implemented callback() within Bubble's scope.  Bubble has no "callback" callback method defined.  this is causing your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. Might b this solves your problem.

```
if($.isFunction(callback)){
    callback.apply();
}
```